# Show that the solution of the initial value problem for $r$ with $r=r_0$ at $t=0$ becomes unbounded as $t→1/2r_0^2$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Show that the solution of the initial value problem for $r$ with $r=r_0$ at $t=0$ becomes unbounded as $t→1/2r_0^2$.

$dx/dt = y + x(x^2+y^2)$, $dy/dt = -x +y(x^2+y^2)$.

In part A I showed that (0,0) is a center and in part B i showed that the system is locally linear.

Since $r^2=x^2+y^2$ and $xdx/dt+ydy/dt = rdr/dt$,

I substituted for $dx/dt$ and $dy/dt$ in the second equation. I also substituted r for $\sqrt(x^2+y^2)$.

After a lot of simplifying, I got that $r^3 = dr/dt$.

I don't know where to proceed. Any help will be greatly appreciated! Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From $r^2 = x^2 + y^2$ we get:

$$r r' = x x' + y y' = x(y + x(x^2+y^2)) + y(-x +y(x^2+y^2)) = r^4 \implies r' = r^3$$

Using Separation of Variables, we arrive at:

$$r(t) = \pm \frac{r_0}{\sqrt{1-2 r_0^2 t}}$$

Now, draw the conclusion that the solution of the initial value problem becomes unbounded as $t \rightarrow \dfrac{1}{2r_0^2}$.